# Google Scripts forEach and setValue not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to have Sheets iterate through the data range, and start another function if two conditions are met.  If the other function is started I want a cell to have the value set.  If the function is not started, it would continue iterating through and increasing the value of i each time.

````
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Repairs")
  var rows = ws.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  rows.forEach(function(eachRow) {
    var i = 1
    var p = 4
    if (eachRow[3].includes("Complete") && (!eachRow[4].includes("Posted"))) {
    var currentMessage = eachRow[0] + "\n" + eachRow[1] + "\n" + eachRow[2]
    RepairsCompleted(currentMessage)
    var cell = ws.getRange(i,4);
    cell.setValue("Posted");
    }
    i++
  });
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `var i = 1` is declared in the loop. By this, `i` is always `1` in every loop. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.

When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
rows.forEach(function(eachRow) {
  var i = 1
```

#### To:

```
var i = 1
rows.forEach(function(eachRow) {
```

#### Note:

- In your script, I thought that the process cost can be reduced a little. So, how about the following modification?

  ```
    function sample() {
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Repairs")
      var rows = ws.getDataRange().getValues();

      // I modified the below script.
      const ranges = rows.flatMap(function (eachRow, i) {
        if (eachRow[3].includes("Complete") && (!eachRow[4].includes("Posted"))) {
          var currentMessage = eachRow[0] + "\n" + eachRow[1] + "\n" + eachRow[2]
          RepairsCompleted(currentMessage);
          return ["D" + (i + 1)];
        }
        return [];
      });
      if (ranges.length == 0) return;
      ws.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("Posted");
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)

Comment: Thank you, I looked at that thing for an hour trying to figure out why it didn't work and missed that every time.  That fixed it.

Comment: @Xiael Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Repairs")
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[3].includes("Complete") && (!r[4].includes("Posted"))) {
      let currentMessage = r[0] + "\n" + r[1] + "\n" + r[2]
      RepairsCompleted(currentMessage)
      sh.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue("Posted");
    }
  });
}
```